# How to customize the Jira Issue Collector form that pops up?

Tags: html, forms, jira

[image: screenshot of the current issue collector popup form]

Above is what the Issue Collector pop-up form looks like at the moment. This is used to report bugs on a mobile app. When creating the Issue Collector on Jira, I opted for a custom trigger style and a custom template. On Jira, my customization of the template (i.e. the Issue Collector form) is very limited.

I would like to modify the form so that:

1. More fields (eg Name & Email) are marked 'required', right now only the Summary is marked 'required'.
2. Multiple fields are displayed on the form. These fields will collect data on, for example OS version, and other specific details.

Is there a way to access the form's HTML code where I can make changes to elements and add more? Otherwise, how can I achieve this through another method?

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same question. At the moment, I failed to customize this popup. I could only set some default values as Jira documentation explains it (here https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/customize-the-jira-issue-collector/).

In the javascript that is used to call the Jira issue collector, I try to interact with the modal with no success. Because it's an iframe, my browser won't let me access it at all.

On a side note, you can probably style your popup using this Jira plugin : https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221494/revitalized-issue-collector-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview
I have not tried it yet.

Some other people have the same question without great answers :

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/how-to-implement-custom-css-on-jira-issue-collector/qaq-p/668213

also :

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Issue-Collector-is-it-possible-to-change-the-look-of-the-issue/qaq-p/1003696

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).